# sinunitx: prefixes and exponents confusion with complex numbers

Tags: siunitx

I want siunitx to typeset a complex quantity. My numerical input is (0,25 + 0,25i). MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx} %
\sisetup{
  exponent-mode = engineering,
  prefix-mode = combine-exponent
}
\begin{document}
  $\complexqty{0,25 + 0,25i}{\ohm}$
\end{document}
```

I would expect either (250 + 250i)mOhm or (250 + 250i)*10^-3 Ohm. Actually I get both combined, which is obviously wrong:
[image]

Has someone a fix for it?

Comment: In document preamble try add `babel` package. Adding it I got desired result. Tested with recent `siunitx` (v3.0.47, last revised 2022-02-03).

Comment: I get what looks like the right result: which version of `siunitx` do you have?

Comment: Problem solved :-) Yes, it was an old version of 'siunitx'... After update it works as expected. Even without installing 'babel'. Thank you very much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by an outdated package version, readily updatable to the current working release.